# Is left-factoring of grammar necessary in Bison?

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison, bnf

I am making a parser using bison. I just wanna ask if it still necessary for a grammar to be left-factored when used in bison. I tried giving bison a non-left-factored grammar and it didn't gave any warning or error and it also accepted the example syntax I gave to the parser, but I'm worried that it the parser may not be accurate in every input.

Comment: Bison uses a LALR parser, no problem with left-recursion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking about left-factoring not left recursion. http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno//CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node9.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left factoring is how you remove LL-conflicts in a grammar. Since Bison uses LALR it has no problems with left recursion or any other LL-conflicts (indeed, left recursion is preferable as it minimizes stack requirements), so left factoring is neither necessary nor desirable.

Note that left factoring won't break anything -- bison can deal with a left-factored grammar as well as a non-left factored one, but it may require more resources (memory) to parse the left-factored grammar, so in general, don't.

**edit**

You seem to be confused about how LL-vs-LR parsing work and how the structure of the grammar affects each.

LL parsing is top down -- you start with just the start symbol on the parse stack, and at each step, you replace the non-terminal on top of the stack with the symbols from the right side of some rule for that non-terminal.  When there is a terminal on top of the stack, it must match the next token of input, so you pop it and consume the input.  The goal being to consume all the input and end up with an empty stack.

LR parsing is bottom up -- you start with an empty stack, and at each step you either copy a token from the input to the stack (consuming it), or you replace a sequence of symbols on the top of the stack corresponding to the right side of some rule with the single symbol from the left side of the rule.  The goal being to consume all the input and be left with just the start symbol on the stack.

So different rules for the same non-terminal which start with the same symbols on the right side are a big problem for LL parsing -- you could replace that non-terminal with the symbols from either rule and match the next few tokens of input, so you would need more lookahead to know which to do.  But for LR parsing, there's no problem -- you just shift (move) the tokens from the input to the stack and when you get to the later tokens you decide which right side it matches.

LR parsing tends to have problems with rules that *end* with the same tokens on the right hand side, rather than rules that start with the same tokens.  In your example from John Levine's book, there are rules "cart_animal ::= HORSE" and "work_animal ::= HORSE", so after shifting a HORSE symbol, it could be reduced (replace by) either "cart_animal" or "work_animal".  Since the context allows either to be followed by the "AND" token, you end up with a reduce/reduce (LR) conflict when the next token is "AND".

Comment: I think left factoring and left recursion are two different topics, but anyway, thanks for making it clear that left-factoring isnt necessary. The book I am reading about bison, Flex & Bison by John Levine, said implicitly that bison can't handle non-left-factored grammars (page 50), which made me confused.

Comment: I'm a newbie in parsing, so please correct me if i'm wrong,  left factoring and left recursion are different topics. Left recursion is when LHS appears in the leftmost RHS; like A-> A b. Left factoring is the elimination of several leftmost symbols that are the same in different alternatives so an algorithm that requires ONE token of lookahead, like LALR(1), can effectively parse the grammar. For example, A -> B C x | B C xz; must be left-factored to A -> Dx | A -> Dxz; D -> B C; . This means left-factoring doesn't eliminates left recursion but rather reducing the lookahead into one symbol

Comment: Left factoring and left recursion are closely related -- they are both concerned with LL-conflicts in the grammar.  LR parsing doesn't care about LL-conflicts, only LR-conflicts, so both are irrelevant to LR parsers.  Your example only requires 1-token lookahead for LR parsing without any left factoring, as LR parsing deals with sets of simultaneous rules rather than single rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your example only requires 1-token lookahead for LR parsing without any left factoring, as LR parsing deals with sets of simultaneous rules rather than single rules."

Comment: In the book of John Levine, he said that this grammar cannot be parsed by bison ... phrase: cart_animal AND CART | work_animal AND PLOW; cart_animal: HORSE | GOAT; work_animal: HORSE | OX

Comment: That example has an LR-conflict, so can't be parsed by bison.  This is completely unrelated to left factoring (and there is no left factoring that can be done with that example grammar, but even if there were, left factoring would have no effect on the LR-conflict).

Comment: He said that in parsing HORSE AND CART, bison cannot tell that HORSE is a cart_animal or a work_animal until it sees CART, but bison cannot look that far.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the opposite is true. Parsers generated by LALR(1) parser generators not only support left recursion, they in fact work *better* with left recursion. Ironically, you may have to refactor *right* recursion out of your grammar.

Right recursion works; however, it delays reduction, causing parse stack space that is proportional to the size of the recursive construct being parsed.

For instance, building a Lisp-style list like this:

```
list : item { $$ = cons($1, nil); }
     | item list { $$ = cons($1, $2); }
```

means that the parser stack is proportional to the length of the list. No reduction takes place until the rightmost `item` is reached, and then a cascade of reductions takes place, building the list from right to left by a sequence of `cons` calls.

You might not encounter this issue until you start parsing data, rather than code, and the data gets large.

If you modify this for left recursion, you can build a the list in a constant amount parser stack, because the action will be "reduce as you go":

```
list : item        { $$ = cons($1, nil); }
     | list item   { $$ = append($1, cons($2, nil)); }
```

(Now there is a performance problem with `append` searching for the tail of the list; for which there are various solutions, unrelated to the parsing.)